# Error al abrir archivo de Excel en GX X EVO 3

Tags: genexus, apache-poi, genexus15, genexusxev3

Estoy tratando de abrir un archivo de excel (extension xls)

```
&Error = &FileExcel.Open(&FileName)
```

Pero obtengo este error

```
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getRoot()
```

Este es el ambiente que utilizo

GX X EVO 3 U7

Ubuntu 20.04

Tomcat 9.0.31

Java version: openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18

Java libraries to handle MS Office: He tratado con dos diferentes versiones:

poi-3.17.jar, poi-ooxml-3.17.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar

poi-3.8.jar, poi-ooxml-3.8.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar

Ademas tambien estoy usando Libreoffice en modo headless, el cual levanto de esta forma:

```
sudo /usr/bin/soffice --nologo --headless --nofirststartwizard --accept='socket, host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service' &
```

He seguido las instrucciones que se detallan en estos links:

https://www5.genexus.com/xev3/scmain.aspx?S%3B178%3B94%3B1264%3B1%3B1%3BO%3B,37721
https://www5.genexus.com/xev3/scmain.aspx?S%3B178%3B94%3B1264%3B1%3B1%3BO%3B,37721

De antemano, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución a este issue, la cual se describe [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74568188/error-at-opening-ms-excel-file-with-gx-x-evo-3).

Saludos

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el contenido principal del enlace en la respuesta misma. Piénsalo: si un día el enlace llega a caer, y alguien con un problema similar llega a tu respuesta, la respuesta estará incompleta. Lee [answer]. Por último, modifica el título de tu pregunta para mostrar cuál era el problema en cuestión.